# How to tell what packages are "official" or a part of the standard Racket distribution?

Tags: package, racket

How does one figure out whether a library is "standard" in a Racket distribution?

Looking at https://docs.racket-lang.org/, it would seem that lots of libraries are included with Racket, but it turns out that only the ones from package `base` are included (correct?), and it's not obvious from that page which is which. I didn't expect [JSON](https://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html) would be in base, but it is. I would've expected [threading](https://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html) to be in base, but it isn't. I was looking at [SRFI/19](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-19/srfi-19.html) which seemed to not be included in standard Racket but it turns out I didn't have to download anything to get it. It's quite confusing.

Then, reading https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/More_Libraries.html, it says:

> The Racket distribution includes many additional libraries.

Does this mean that the Racket distribution also has third-party packages bundled? How do I know what packages are available *out-of-box* and which ones I have to download separately? How do I know which ones are "official" and which ones are community-contributed?

Answer (score 3):

The packages included in the standard Racket distribution are the ones which the [`main-distribution`](https://pkgd.racket-lang.org/pkgn/package/main-distribution) package depends on.

These are tagged with the `main-distribution` tag on the package catalog, so you can see the list here:
https://pkgd.racket-lang.org/pkgn/search?tags=main-distribution

Keep in mind that this is a list of packages, not modules. The `json` module is provided by the `base` package, the `scribble/reader` module is provided by the `at-exp-lib` package, the `framework` module is provided by the `gui-lib` package, and so on.

So if you're wondering whether a *module* is in the main distribution or not, first look up what package it's provided by, and then see whether that package is in the main distribution.